# How to set default orderby in a web2py table?

Tags: python, forms, web2py

Although I consider this a simple task I can't find a way to make it work when using a `SQLFORM`. Let's say I have this structure as an example:

```
db.define_table('month',
    Field('name', 'string'),
    format='%(nombre)s'
)

db.define_table('foo'
    Field('bar', 'string'),
    Field('month', db.month), # I want to sort this by ID
    format='%(bar)s'
)

db.month.update_or_insert(id=1, nombre='January')
db.month.update_or_insert(id=2, nombre='Frebruary')
# ...
db.month.update_or_insert(id=12, nombre='December')
```

In the view:

```
def example():
    form = SQLFORM(db.foo).process()
    if form.accepted:
        redirect(URL('default', 'foo'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

The `form` is sorting the months alphabetically and that is not the desire behavior, I want to show the months ordered by ID. Is there a way to set the default order in a table?

```
db.month.orderby = db.month.id # Not working
db.month._orderby = db.month.id # Not working
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db.foo.month` field is a reference field, and by default, it gets an `IS_IN_DB` validator, which results in the select widget being generated in the form. The select widget includes the IDs of the "month" table records as values, but it displays the month names in the dropdown because of the "format" attribute of the `db.month` table. By default, the items in the dropdown end up being ordered by the fields specified in the format string (in this case, the month names). To change that, you can manually define the validator and specify the "orderby" argument:

```
db.foo.month.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'month.id', db.month._format,
                                 orderby=db.month.id)
```

Comment: This may not be the best place to ask this, but what if month had a foreign key and I wanted to sort based on some field of that? Say `orderby=db.month.foobar_id.name` or some such?

Comment: In that case, you would probably have to build the set of values and labels manually and instead use the `IS_IN_SET` validator.