# web2py sort order in dropdown when format attribute of reference table is function

Tags: python, sorting, web2py

The Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238708/how-to-set-default-orderby-in-a-web2py-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267488/web2py-representation-format-in-grandchild) appear to indicate that the default sort order in the dropdown made by IS_IN_DB validator is determined by the format attribute of the referenced table. But in the following case, the default sort order is the 'id' of the referenced table:

```
db.define_table('bank',
            Field('bank_code', 'string',
                  unique=True, required=True, label='Bank/FI Code'),
            Field('bank_name', 'string',
                  required=True, label='Bank/FI Name'),
            singular="Bank", plural="Banks",
            format='%(bank_name)s'
            )

db.bank.bank_code.requires=IS_UPPER()
db.bank.bank_name.requires=IS_UPPER()

db.define_table('bank_branch',
            Field('bank', 'reference bank', label='Bank/FI'),
            Field('branch_name', 'string', required=True, label='Branch Name'),
            format=lambda r:'%s-%s' % (r.bank.bank_code, r.branch_name)
```

Even though the dropdown labels display the labels returned by the lambda function of the table `bank_branch`, they are sorted on its id field.

It is advised [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/yqhP5VUvuPY/labEqm0lBQAJ) to use IS_IN_SET for such situations, but what can be the explanation for the normal behaviour of sorting on the basis of 'format' attribute getting changed when such format is done by lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when the `IS_IN_DB` validator generates the set of values and associated labels, it does not directly sort by the generated labels. Rather, in the database select, it specifies an `ORDER BY` clause that includes the fields used to generate the label. If the `format` attribute of the referenced table is a Python format string, the label fields are extracted from that format string in the order they appear. This has the effect of ordering the final set by the labels in that case.

However, if the `format` attribute of the referenced table is a function, `IS_IN_DB` does not know which fields are needed to generate the labels, so it simply selects all fields in the table and orders by all fields (in the order they appear in the table definition). In this case, because `db.bank_branch.id` is the first field in the table definition (though not defined explicitly), that is the first field in the `ORDER BY` clause, resulting in the options being ordered by the IDs of the `db.bank_branch` table.

If you want to force the options to be sorted by the generated labels, you can use the `sort` argument:

```
IS_IN_DB(db, 'bank_branch.id', db.bank_branch._format, sort=True)
```

As an aside, keep in mind that if there are many bank branches, this method of generating labels is somewhat inefficient, as the `format` function includes a recursive select (i.e., `r.bank.brank_code`), which does a separate select for every item in the list. An alternative would be to generate your own set of values and labels based on a join query and then use the `IS_IN_SET` validator (or use `IS_IN_DB` just for the validation, and specify the form widget and its options separately). Of course, at some point, there may be more branches than would be reasonable to include in a select input, in which case, you can use `IS_IN_DB` to do the validation but should use an alternative input widget (e.g., an Ajax autocomplete).

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, for the lucid explanation. One difference I noticed is that the dropdown is sorted not on `bank_branch.bank.id` but on `bank_branch.id`. Presumably `id` will be the first field of the table definition, even though not explicitly defined.

Comment: Thanks also for the caution on using he `sort=True` option. My `bank_branch` table is expected to grow over time to around 100 thousand records, and recursive selects might cause problems eventually. So the `IS_IN_SET` method will have to be followed here, right?

Comment: Sorry, was looking at the wrong code block (the ID is excluded from `orderby` only on Google App Engine). I have corrected the answer. Also, if you'll have 100,000+ records, you won't want to use a select input in the form anyway, as you'll be sending all of those records to the browser, and the user would have an impossibly long list to scroll (assuming the browser doesn't crash). In that case, you should instead use something like an Ajax autocomplete (or maybe limit the list of branches to a subset based on previous selection of a bank, etc.).